# error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, scikits

I have just installed Python 3.8.2 on a Windows 8.1 (64-bit).
When trying to install scikit-sparse module (python -m pip install scikit-sparse
) I get the below error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

The below is the full install script and failure:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scikit-sparse) (1.
18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from scikit-sparse) (1.
4.1)
Installing collected packages: scikit-sparse
    Running setup.py install for scikit-sparse ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
'"'"'C:\\Users\\aldim_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3srmnkwv\\scikit-sparse\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aldim_000\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3srmnkwv\\scikit-sparse\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repl
ace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Loca
l\Temp\pip-record-muu60ly9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\scikit-sparse'
         cwd: C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3srmnkwv\scikit-sparse\
    Complete output (31 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse
    copying sksparse\test_cholmod.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse
    copying sksparse\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse
    copying sksparse\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\illc1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\illc1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\well1033.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\well1033_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\well1850.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    copying sksparse\test_data\well1850_rhs1.mtx.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse\test_data
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse/_version.py
    set build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\sksparse/_version.py to '0.4.4'
    running build_ext
    skipping 'sksparse\cholmod.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'sksparse.cholmod' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sksparse
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\aldim_000\App
Data\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38/include
 -I/usr/include/suitesparse -IC:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\
Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSD
K\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\um" "-IC
:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\\winrt" /Tcsksparse\cholmod.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\sksparse\cholmod.obj
    cholmod.c
    c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warn
ing Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3srmnkwv\scikit-sparse\sksparse\cholmod_backward_compatible.h(1): fatal error C1083: C
annot open include file: 'cholmod.h': No such file or directory
    c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Wa
ing Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
    c:\users\aldim_000\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-3srmnkwv\scikit-sparse\sksparse\cholmod_backward_compatible.h(1): fatal error C1083:
annot open include file: 'cholmod.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, s
uptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aldim_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3srmnkwv\\scikit-sparse\\setup.py'"'"'; __fi
__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aldim_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3srmnkwv\\scikit-sparse\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"',
pen)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --reco
 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-muu60ly9\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-he
ers 'C:\Users\aldim_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\scikit-sparse' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Have you find any solution to your problem ? I have the same issue when tried to install pyodbc into PyCharm terminal. I have Python 3.8.2 on Windows 7

Comment: No, what I did was install linux / ubuntu on a virtual machine, so I was able to install the module.

Comment: In Windows 8, you tried to download pyodbc on a project created in a virtual environment or not? If yes, it can be the problem. If the project is not in a  virtual environment, I think you can install pyodbc easily.

Comment: My problem was installing scikit-sparse.  But it didn't matter if the installation was in a virtual environment or not, the problem persisted.